# How did God send His Spirit to the Israelites in the wilderness?

Tags: spirit, nehemiah

Nehemiah 9:20 NASB

> You gave Your good Spirit to instruct [the Israelites], your manna you did not withhold from their mouth, And you gave them water for their thirst.

How did God give His spirit to the Israelites? Is this verse talking about His Spirit through the prophets or something more?

Versus 30 mentions God admonishing the Israelites “by Your Spirit through Your prophets” but I’m wondering whether verse 20 is referring to another way God sent His Spirit to His people.

Comment: Perhaps some context to the Q might be helpful... how? Why how, He just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did God send His Spirit to the Israelites in the wilderness?

One answer can be found in Numbers 11

> 17 I will come down and speak with you there, and I will take some of the power of the **Spirit** that is on you and put it on them. They will share the burden of the people with you so that you will not have to carry it alone. ...
> 25 Then the LORD came down in the cloud and spoke to him, and He took some of the **Spirit** that was on Moses and placed that **Spirit on the seventy elders**.

The Holy Spirit rested on Moses and the 70 elders. They instructed the Israelites.